# Unzip all zip files in a directory without overwriting?

Tags: macos, zip

I'm working in OSX. I have a lot of zip files in a directory called `data` and I would like to unzip them all:

```
$ ls data
62.zip
63.zip
64.zip
...
```

I'm using the following command:

```
unzip -d data "data/*"
```

The problem I'm having is that all the files are unzipping to the same target directory, called `10.002`, and being overwritten each time. So I end up with only one unzipped file.

How can I make each file unzip to its own unique directory?

Or even better, have all the files unzip to the same directory, but without being overwritten.

Comment: use -n option on unzip to never overwrite existing files

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [The Unarchiver](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12) (freeware) that has prefs for extraction, to put every archive in a separate folder, if there's any danger they contain files of the same name you don't want overwriting.

Alternatively, [Stuffit Expander](http://my.smithmicro.com/stuffit-expander-mac.html) (freeware) can be set to automatically rename any conflicts.